# Passing variables to the MYSQL Query from Command line

Tags: mysql-python

I don't want to burden people with my whole code,
So i'm going to try to only get parts that could help answer my question

I need to add a date range as an input to my python call

```
python query2.py -v --start_date='2013-08-12' --finish_date='2013-08-15' > output.txt
```

But when I try to add this as a concatenation string to the SQL_QUERY variable in the query subroutine I get this error:

```
    SQL_QUERY += """ HAVING sm.created >= '2013-08-12' and sm.created <= '2013-0
8-15' """
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'SQL_QUERY' referenced before assignment
Killed by signal 2.
```

So im guessing I cant add the variable in that manner,

```
SQL_QUERY += " HAVING sm.created >= " + options.db_start + " and sm.created <= " + options.db_finish
```

Could someone tell me what wrong?

Thanks

```
import sys
import os
import time
import optparse
import getpass
import subprocess
from contextlib import contextmanager
import MySQLdb


# TODO: modify this with columns, course_id that make sense for you
SQL_QUERY = """
select au.email, sm.created, sce.created , sm.grade, sm.max_grade
from auth_user au, courseware_studentmodule sm,  student_courseenrollment sce
where sm.student_id = au.id and sm.student_id = sce.id
and sm.course_id = 'MyCourse'
and sm.module_type = 'problem' 
"""

def query():
    """

    SQL_QUERY += " HAVING sm.created >= " + options.db_start + " and sm.created <= " + options.db_finish
    log_info("query = %s" % SQL_QUERY)
    result = None
    conn = None
    try:
        conn = MySQLdb.connect(host='127.0.0.1', 
                port=options.local_port,
                user=options.db_user, 
                passwd=options.db_password, 
                db=options.db_name);
        cur = conn.cursor()
        cur.execute(SQL_QUERY)
        result = cur.fetchall()
    except MySQLdb.Error as e:
        sys.stderr.write("Database error %d: %s\n" % (e.args[0],e.args[1]))
    if conn:
        conn.close()
    return result


def parse_command_line():
    usage = """usage: %prog [options]

 parser.add_option("--start_date", dest="db_start", 
        help="Database host (default=\"%s\"" % DEFAULT_DB_HOST)
    parser.add_option("--finish_date", dest="db_finish", 
        help="Database host (default=\"%s\"" % DEFAULT_DB_HOST)
    global options
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `query()` function you must use `global SQL_QUERY` first. What's going on here is that Python assumes that any name that is assigned to, anywhere within a function, is local to that function unless explicitly told otherwise. If it is only reading from a name, and the name doesn't exist locally, it will try to look up the name in any containing scopes (e.g. the module's global scope).